# Unable to run Add-PowerBIWorkspaceUser with variables

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I have a short script that creates a PowerBI Workspace, an Azure AD Group, and in the end adds this group as admin for the workspace.

When I run these commands without the variables and just add the workspace ID string and group GUID string into the Add-PowerBIWorkspaceUser it works fine. When I run the command with variables it breaks.

This will work

```
Add-PowerBIWorkspaceUser -Scope Individual -Id myWorkSpaceIDasString -Identifier myIdentifierAsString -AccessRight Admin -PrincipalType Group
```

This breaks

```
$workspace = New-PowerBIWorkspace -Name test1
$administrator = New-AzADGroup -DisplayName "test1 admin" -MailNickName "test1_admin"
Add-PowerBIWorkspaceUser -Scope Individual -Id $workspace.id -Identifier $administrator.id -AccessRight Admin -PrincipalType Group -Verbose
```

Verbose output from command

> Add-PowerBIWorkspaceUser: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
> VERBOSE: Request Uri: https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/9f97ab99-c144-4abb-9952-009311ecd389/users
> VERBOSE: Status Code: NotFound (404)

Do note that Write-Host $workspace and $administrator works fine and the actual ID as a string is being output from the command.

When running Resolve-PowerBIError -Last this is the output

```
   HistoryId: 101

RequestId        : 542a46ef-642a-40c4-8eb7-fe79a9d76c21
Response         : Not Found (404): {"error":{"code":"PowerBIEntityNotFound","pbi.error":{"code":"PowerBIEntityNotFound","parameters":{},"details":[],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}
PowerBIErrorInfo :
ResponseDate     : Mon, 01 Nov 2021 11:32:01 GMT
RequestMethod    : POST
RequestUri       : https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/d33c94f4-da97-4d85-9433-5c23cff699a3/users
InvocationInfo   : {Add-PowerBIWorkspaceUser}
Line             : Add-PowerBIWorkspaceUser -Scope Individual -Id $workspace.id -Identifier $administrator.id -AccessRight Admin -PrincipalType Group -Verbose
Position         : At line:1 char:1
                   + Add-PowerBIWorkspaceUser -Scope Individual -Id $workspace.id -Identif …
                   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
StackTrace       :    at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.Groups.AddGroupUserWithHttpMessagesAsync(String groupId, GroupUserAccessRight userDetails, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   
                      at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.GroupsExtensions.AddGroupUserAsync(IGroups operations, String groupId, GroupUserAccessRight userDetails, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
                      at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.GroupsExtensions.AddGroupUser(IGroups operations, String groupId, GroupUserAccessRight userDetails)
                      at Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Workspaces.AddPowerBIWorkspaceUser.ExecuteCmdlet()
                      at Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Common.PowerBICmdlet.ProcessRecord()
HistoryId        : 101
```

To me it doesn't look like the variables are replaced at all in the command. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The "this breaks" code looks syntactically good, but I've noted that the error message shows  different arguments (e. g. `-Id $workspace` instead of `-Id $workspace.id`. Are you sure you have run the current version of your code?

Comment: @zett42 Absolutely. I even tried execute it line by line directly in Powershell. However. I forgot to update the error after doing some minor changes to the script for visibility. Updated the error now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. There seems to be some sync delay between Azure AD and PowerBI. Can't find any info online about how long this delay is.

I added a simple `Start-Sleep -s 30`, but a proper backoff/retry function should probably be implemented.